# Sets and ordinals - homework questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I have two questions which I don't even know how to start. I would like you to give some hints. I know it would be better that I show some work, but I really don't know where to begin...

The question goes like that:

> Find whether the sets are isomorphic and whether the order types are equal.

1. $\omega\cdot{\omega}$ and $\omega+\omega$ where $\omega$ is the first infinite ordinal.
2. $q+1+q$ and $q\cdot{q}$ where q is the order type of $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINTS:**

1. Note that there is just one limit ordinal smaller than $\omega+\omega$.
2. <del>Only one of these orders is dense.</del> Two countable dense orders with the same endpoints are isomorphic. (Thank you bof for the correction.)

Comment: D'oh, it's strange how immediately I see this after a sleepless night, whereas 10 hours ago I was relatively fresh as a morning dew. I'll fix this soon.

Comment: Thanks, Asaf, your hint for 1 is helpful, I still don't know how to answer two - What is the meaning of "dense with same endpoints"?

Comment: @Galc127: I mean the same configuration of existence of minimum and maximum. Dense just means that between two points there is a third.

Comment: That make sense. Thank you for your helpful answers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila how can we approach this without mentioning that it's dense. (Because our professor said we won't cover dense).

Comment: @GinKin: I don't think that I know any reasonable isomorphisms between the two sets; once you know that all dense countable sets without endpoints are isomorphic there's little point in working any harder. It's not hard to show that the first one is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ (by mapping the first $q$ to the negative rationals; the $1$ to $0$ and the second $q$ to the positive rationals). But I can't think of anything simple enough for the second one.

Comment: Isn't mapping $(a,b)\in\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q \to \frac ab\in \mathbb Q$ a good enough function ?

Comment: @GinKin: It's not injective, nor it is order preserving.